# datatable server side processing gives error

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter-4 and i am inplementing datatable server side processing.

I found following error:

> "DataTables warning: table id=admin_user_datatable - Requested unknown
> parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
> error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22)

After this error, data is loading in server table.

controller:

```
    public function ajaxDataTables()
    { 
         
            $params['draw'] = @$_POST['draw'];
            $start = @$_POST['start'];
            $length = @$_POST['length'];
            $search_value = @$_POST['search']['value'];

           if(!empty($search_value)){
                $total_count = $this->db->query("SELECT employee_name,employee_email,employee_phone from users WHERE id like '%".$search_value."%' OR employee_name like '%".$search_value."%' OR  employee_email like '%".$search_value."%' OR employee_phone like '%".$search_value."%'")->getResult();

                $data = $this->$db->query("SELECT employee_name,employee_email,employee_phone from users WHERE id like '%".$search_value."%' OR employee_name like '%".$search_value."%' OR employee_email like '%".$search_value."%' OR employee_phone like '%".$search_value."%' limit $start, $length")->getResult();

            }else{
                // count all data
                $total_count = $this->db->query("SELECT employee_name,employee_email,employee_phone from users")->getResult();

                // get per page data
                $data = $this->db->query("SELECT employee_name,employee_email,employee_phone from users limit $start, $length")->getResult();
            }
            $no = @$_POST['start'];
            foreach ($data as $employee) {
                $no++;
                $row = array();
                $row[] = $no;
                $row[] = $employee->employee_name;
                $row[] = $employee->employee_email;
                $row[] = $employee->employee_phone;
                $row[] ='<a href=""><span class="role member">Update</span></a> || <a href=""><span class="role admin">Delete</span></a>';
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            $json_data = array(
            "draw" => @$_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => count($total_count),
            "recordsFiltered" => count($total_count),
            "data" => $data   // total data array
            );

            echo json_encode($json_data);
}

<script>

    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";

    $(document).ready( function () {

        $('#admin_user_datatable').DataTable({
          paginationType: "full_numbers",
          lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
          processing: true,
          serverSide: true,
          scrollY: "400px",
          scrollCollapse: true,
          ajax: {
            url: site_url + "/ajax-datatable", // json datasource
            type: "post",
            data: {
              // key1: value1 - in case if we want send data with request
            }
          },
          columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false, targets: [0] }
          ],
          bFilter: true, // to display datatable search
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Please be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection! Please have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How does the generated response differ from the expected?

Comment: @NicoHaase  DataTables warning: table id=admin_user_datatable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 this is occur

Comment: And what have you tried to check **why** this error occurs?